# Why regular expression in visual studio not working in program?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I am able to get a match using regular expression search in visual studio.

(/:d.*.csv)  matches  "/06-10-2009-TO-05-10-2011SBINALLN.csv"  in "/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/06-10-2009-TO-05-10-2011SBINALLN.csv"

However the same RegEx does not work programmatically as shown below:

```
    static private string GetFileName(string url)
    {
        // (/:d.*\.csv)  this RegEx works in visual studio!
        Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"(/:d.*\.csv)");
        string key = null;
        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        return key;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean works in Visual Studio

Comment: Visual Studio's search regular expressions are NOT identical to .Net Regex regular expressions.

Comment: @msarchet    Visual studio search(ctrl+F) using regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that :d works in visual studio regular expression search, but not in Regex.Match, when i tried the code below, it worked. Used [0-9] instead of :d. As commented by  [Joel Rondeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240313/joel-rondeau), Visual Studio RegEx seems to be different from .NET RegEx.

```
    static private string GetFileName(string url)
    {
        // (/:d[^"]*\.csv)  this RegEx works in visual studio!
        Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"(/[0-9].*\.csv)");
        string key = null;
        // Here we check the Match instance.
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
            key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        key = key.Replace("/", "");
        return key;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works just fine - the RegEx just isn't matching like you think it is. It appears that you're trying to get the last part of the path. If so, use the code below:

```
static private string GetFileName(string url)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"/[^/]*$");
    string key = null;

    if (match.Success)
    {
        key = match.Value;
    }

    return key; //Returns "/06-10-2009-TO-05-10-2011SBINALLN.csv"
}
```

**Alternative**

You could also use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url)`.

```
static private string GetFileName(string url)
{
    // Returns "06-10-2009-TO-05-10-2011SBINALLN.csv" (removes backslash)
    return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the last part of the filename, use this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName("/content/equities/scripvol/datafiles/06-10-2009-TO-05-10-2011SBINALLN.csv");
```

Comment: @MKV - I wondered about this at first, but tested in LINQPad before posting. It works fine. This is because `Path` handles any form of UNC path, including stuff in the form of `schema://path/to/resource`.

Comment: @Polynomial, +1! Gotta love LINQPad :)